# retrieving data from two related data through third table but all the information from one of them but not all from another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, one is the customers and the other the machines.

I want the customer enter his/her name and the machine model and then all the information from the machines appear in the datagrid. But at the same time just the information for customer in the same datagridview be shown.

I related the tables through a third table ( Orders) but when I select with joining the tables to each other, just the information for the machines appeared which are related to the specific customer not all.

I don’t know how can I show all the information for machines but just information of one specific customer_

My select command is

```
SELECT c.name ,c.Land , m.[Name of Machine]
FROM customers  c
INNER JOIN Orders o ON c.customerNO = o.customerNO
INNER JOIN machins  m ON  o.maschinID = m.machins
WHERE c.name = '" & txtName.Text & "' "
```

appreciated

Comment: it works but it gives just the Information of exact machines which the customer enters in the text box and not all the machines

Comment: Please provide some sample. It's a little hard to understand your requirement.

Comment: I am a little confused @Karl. What is the questions around the datagrid? Do you get the right data back in the query, and your problem is the display? Or is the problem in your query?

Comment: so sorry, I want for example when customer enters 
his Name 
machine model
  at first I should be able to Show in the table HIS INFORMATION
and the INFORMATION OF CHOSEN MACHINE
but later when it press a key , 
the Information for himself plus all the Information for all machines should be displayed
I hope I could clear my Problem
again sorry and thanks

Comment: @karl, if after click you need to show all the information for all machines then don't use join there, or you meant "all information for all the machines the customer owns"?

Comment: I understand you but at the same time I Need the Information for the user himself in the same table, if I dont use join how can I select from different tables _ can I ? i am new in join issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change the INNER JOIN of machins to a RIGHT OUTER JOIN.

This will get all machines, even if they are not related to a customer.

However you will need to also change your WHERE clause to not filter out the rows where no customer is related to the machine:

```
WHERE c.name = 'name from textbox' OR c.name IS NULL
```

Comment: I think you understand my problem, i will try it, thank you for your time

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried it . It works, but i wanted to instead of null names write the names of customer

Comment: Now I have a table like this

Comment: Karl     machine1
Karl      machine2
Karl      machine3
Null       machine 4
I need instead of  Null write  karl

It should be
Karl     machine1
Karl      machine2
Karl      machine3
Karl      machine 4

But the problem of showing the machines now is solved thank you very much